# How to get logs from Docker with journald driver?

Tags: systemd, logs, opensuse, docker, systemd-journald

OpenSuse Tumbleweed + Docker 17.04. I created /etc/docker/daemon.json with:

```
{
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "log-opts": {
            "labels": "my_test",
            "env": "os,customer"
    }
}
```

Then I started docker daemon: `systemctl start docker`. Checked it: `sudo docker info|grep Logg` and see `journald` as current default driver. Also `sudo docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' MY-CONTAINER-ID` shows me `journald` again. Docker was run as

```
sudo docker run -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup --tmpfs /run/dbus --tmpfs /run/lock --cap-add=ALL MY-CONTAINER
```

and then I SH-ed to it. In Docker I made several log-messages with:

```
logger XXX
logger -p local0.notice XXX
# etc...
```

I'm see these messages in Docker journald with `journalctl -n ...`.
And I supposed that I'll find those log-messages in the container ("host OS") too: with `journalctl -n ...` - nothing. With `docker logs MY-CONTAINER-ID` - nothing too. I want to log messages from Docker to container ("host") journald. Configuration looks right, but log messages are missing. Would somebody help me - what is wrong with Docker on OpenSuse/with my configuration?

Comment: Hmm, I added `-v /dev/log:/dev/log` and it seems to work now, so question is - is it dirty hack or Docker documentation lacks this mandatory mount-point?

Comment: seems that it's workaround only

Answer (score 1):

docker journald driver captures the stdout and stderr of the container process.

On the other hand, logger command sends a messase to `/dev/log`.

**Edit**

It would be nice to do `logger -s`

Comment: My container process starts by cron, so no stdout/stderr. Loggins happens through Haskell logging library, but without Docker I see log-messages in systemd journal.

Comment: It depends on your logging library setting. If it is configured to emit a log to journald, use -v /run/systemd/journal/socket:/run/systemd/journal/socket . If it is configured to emit a log to syslog , use -v /dev/log:/dev/log . If it is configured.to emit a log to stderr, docker log driver has to capture it.

Comment: Seems that -v /dev/log works. But what does log driver journald in this case?! Nothing? First, I supposed that this magic log-driver does all work and I don't need to mount socket or log storage from the host...

Comment: What docker log driver does is just to capture stdout and stderr of a continered process. No magic! If your containered process emits a log only to syslog, docker log driver captures no log.

Comment: One suggestion. If your process is haskell, logging-facade-journald may help you, though I do not know haskell well. https://github.com/sol/logging-facade/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Oh, it's true :) But I use `hslogger` package